# TFS 2010 - Good Way to Copy queries/documents from an old iterateration into a new one?

Tags: tfs

I've completed an iteration in TFS 2010, and am preparing to start a new iteration.  I noticed that the MSF Agile 5.0 template does not have all the queries/documents that the first iteration does.

I'm looking for a quick way to copy and update all the queries/documents into my new iteration, without having to copy/paste each item and update the iteration manually. In addition, set up a new SharePoint folder and any other stuff that is tagged to an iteration.   Is there anything out there that can do this?

Comment: What kind of documents do you have that are tied to the iteration?

Comment: The standard Excel documents that come with the MSF Agile template, most importantly, the Iteration Backlog.xlsm file.  I could make a copy and update the TFS connection within the file, but that seems like a hack, would much prefer a more automated way of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way we 've found is described in this [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/07/28/soup-to-nuts-tfs-2010-agile-iteration-backlog-workbook-utilized-in-the-real-world.aspx).

Although it's not fully automated (as a "push-a-button"), I personally don't mind repeating these steps with every new iteration - at least not too much.

Comment: Thanks, in addition to the docs, I guess you just need to copy the iteration queries that you'll need in the new iteration and update them accordingly.